Spring Boot 3.3 Reloadable Properties
(Yes, I've done the research and read the previous questions about this same topic.)
I have a Spring Boot 3.3 application functioning as a REST API. I need to be able to detect changes to an external properties file so I don't have to restart the entire application to pick up changes.
Most of the answers involve Spring Cloud and using @RefreshScope on my beans. However, I do not have a separate Spring Configuration Service, and management is unlikely to approve setting one up. I also do not run Actuator, as the same management it not comfortable exposing the actuator endpoints.
Given these restrictions, is Spring Cloud still the way to go? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole point of Spring Cloud, but it seems like overkill just to be able to access the @RefreshScope feature.

Use Spring Cloud you don't need a configuration service, just use it to enable refreshscope. If you don't you will re-invent your own crappy implementation of the same.
